# When does SonarQube plugin run unit test?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube4.2 with jekins plugin. I configured Sonar as Post-Build Action on Jenkins, and It's work fine. I'm wondering that if maven compiles test sources before executing the sonar action, sonar automatically run these test units, but maven only compiles main sources, then sonar doesn't run unit tests. If Jenkins execute mvn test phase before Sonar as Post=Build Action, Jenkins duplicate running unit tests. I want to compile sources, running unit tests and executing Sonar, hence I configured mvn test-compile with Post-Build Action for Sonar in Job. Is it usual way? Does any body knows better way to executiong sonar with Jenkins.

Regards

Comment: Can you precise the version of the Java plugin you are using ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using maven3.1.1, jdk1.7.0_51, maven-compiler-plugin 2.3.2 targeted 1.6, Jenkins's sonar plugin 2.1 and SonarQube 4.2. Are these versions incorrect? regard

Comment: I would need to know the version of the Java plugin installed on your sonarqube instance. Check your admin settings.
What you need to know is that after version 2.2 Sonar Java plugin does not run the unit tests anymore and it is your responsability to run them and to generate the coverage report.
And one more precision : please use fixed version 2.2.1 of Java Plugin and 1.6.1 of Cobertura as 2.2 and 1.6 contains some bugs.

Comment: Thank you for an additional advice. I could solve my problem by your advice. My sonarqube used Java plugin 2.1, and I updated the plugin. then Jenkins's sonar plugin doesn't run unit tests automatically. Regaed